# How to pass two conditions as parameters to get() query in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have passed two conditions to the filter() method so it is returning queryset .

But how to pass those two conditions to the get() method in order to get response as single object

**Code:**

```
class DailyHolidayView(APIView):
  def post(self,request):
      city_name=request.data['city_name']
      date=datetime.strptime(request.data['date'], '%d/%m/%Y')
      print(date)
      res=Holiday.objects.filter(city_name=city_name,date=date)

      if (res):
           ser = MonthSerializer(res, many=True)
           return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Because i am getting error as below:

AssertionError: [{'id': 12, 'date': '05/01/2019', 'holidayName': 'testHoliday2'}] != {'id': 12, 'date': '05/01/2019', 'holidayName': 'testHoliday2'}

Comment: `.get(**kwargs)` is basically a `.filter(**kwargs).first()`

Comment: If you get a single object then you will probably want to remove `many=True` from your call to the serializer so you are not returning a list

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()`, you return a list, if you just want one object as response, you need to use the `get()` method. In your case, you might also want to use `get_object_or_404` in case the object does not exist. Finally you don't need the `many=true` in your serializer.

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class DailyHolidayView(APIView):
  def post(self,request):
      city_name=request.data['city_name']
      date=datetime.strptime(request.data['date'], '%d/%m/%Y')
      print(date)
      res=get_object_or_404(Holiday, city_name=city_name,date=date)

      if (res):
           ser = MonthSerializer(res)
           return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```